# YA fiction novel about a boy who discovered the power of runes as seen in Norse mythology

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, norse-gods

I'm looking for a book I read as a teen, it was about a boy (his sister became a main character as well) (modern day) who discovered the power of runes as seen in Norse mythology.

Comment: This is very terse can you remember anything else that happens in the book you could [edit] in? Also when we’re you a teen?

Comment: This description fits hundreds of books and is a trope  (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InstantRunes). You need to be much more specific

Comment: I think it was "The Runestone Saga". Thanks anyway!

Comment: @CaseyLeigh If you've found your answer you can answer your own question with that it is!

Comment: It really is a very bare question... we only really have the answer because Casey provided it. Maybe we ought to ask ourselves if this will be of use to anyone.

Comment: Casey, please feel free to post your own answer, taking whatever you wish from mine. Or you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Casey indicated in the comments that they believe the book to be from *The Runestone Saga*, by Chris Humphreys. The first book, *[The Fetch](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/526178.The_Fetch)*, published in 2006, has Sky and his cousin finding Norwegian runes belonging to their grandfather.

[image: Front cover of The Fetch]

> In the attic, in an old sea chest, secreted away, are a mysterious journal and a set of runes: 24 stones that will change Sky's life forever.
>
> When Sky and his cousin Kristin find their Norwegian grandfather's runes, Sky feels like the wait is over, like he can now release the breath he wasn't even aware he'd been holding. But when he lays out the stones in a runecast they find in Sigurd's journal, he is catapulted into a world filled with more possibilities and more danger than he ever imagined.

The [Kirkus Review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/chris-humphreys/the-fetch/) of the book provides a bit more detail about the supernatural and time travel aspects of the book.

> A boy is drawn into the violent past of his grandfather and Viking ancestors. Sky’s not looking forward to a summer with his estranged cousin Kristin, until they find Grandfather Sigurd’s runes in an old chest in the attic. Runecasting leads Sky to animal shapeshifting, dangerous haunts and visions of going a-Viking with his berserker forefather, Bjorn. Sky and Kristin run off to Norway on a mysterious quest, where they discover that Sigurd is neither so dead, nor so benevolent, as they’d originally suspected. Sky’s lessons in unexpectedly potent violence lead him to some hard decisions. The cousins slog through overwritten prose (though some historical Viking scenes are brought beautifully to life with language reminiscent of Anglo-Saxon alliterative rhythms). Despite pacing, a compelling adventure that asks hard questions of its characters.